# The HLS segment filename file path not incrementing

Tags: ffmpeg, backend, child-process, spawn

```
const ffmpegProcess = spawn(ffmpeg [
'-y','-i','/home/Documents/videotrans/video-transcoder/api/videoFiles/input/sample2.mp4',
'-s:v','1280x720',
'-b:v','2000000',
'-aspect','16:9',
'-b:a','64000',
'-r', '24',
'-s:v','854x480',
'-b:v','1000000',
'-aspect','16:9',
'-b:a', '112000',
'-r', '24',
'-s:v','640x360',
'-b:v','7000000',
'-aspect','16:9',
'-b:a','80000',
'-r', '24',
'-s:v','420x420',
'-b:v','600000',
'-aspect','16:9',
'-b:a','64000',
'-r', '24',
'-sc_threshold', '0',
'-map','0:0',
'-map','0:1',
'-map','0:0',
'-map','0:1',
'-map','0:0',
'-map','0:1',
'-map','0:0',
'-map','0:1',
'-ac','2',
'-ar','44100',
'-preset','slow',
'-var_stream_map','v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3',
'-f','hls',
'-hls_list_size','0',
'-master_pl_name','master.m3u8',
'-hls_segment_filename','/home/Documents/videotrans/video-transcoder/api/videoFiles/output/v%v/fileSequence~%03d.ts',
'/home/Documents/videotrans/video-transcoder/api/videoFiles/output/v%v/prog_index.m3u8'
]);
```

Here I'm using the spawn of a child process of FFMPEG I need to transcode the video input into four different resolutions in m3u8 format. There will be master.m3u8 and folders v0, v1, v2, and v3; inside those folders, there should be pro_index.m3u8 file and multiple file-sequence files according to input file size

The HLS segment filename is not incrementing properly So the process is failing

how to increment fileSequence file names?
fileSequence%d.ts or fileSequence%03d.ts in not work here

Answer (score 0):

so the ~ is probably causing problems you need to use something like this

```
/home/Documents/videotrans/video-transcoder/api/videoFiles/output/v%v/fileSequence_%03d.ts
```

also this "v%v" could be an issue as well it shouldn't be but it would be best if you rename that folder